# Installing SSL on Shared hosting server

Tags: ssl, sudo, ssl-certificate

I have beta invitation of `letsencrypt.org` I followed there documentation here . But i am unable to install there packages because i have shared hosting server which does not allow to use `sudo` commands. How can i install letsencrypt without sudo commands?

Previously i was using Free trial Ssl certificate on Comodo which expired today. As i far as i know i cannot renew it for free. Am i wrong?

I have my mail configured with ssl port will it cause any problems now as my certificate has expired?

Comment: If you can't follow the instructions then you can't use lets encrypt certificates